# How to make calculations on certain cells (within a table) that meet specific criteria?

Tags: matlab, for-loop, cell-array, matlab-table

I have the following code:

```
L_sum = zeros(height(ABC),1);
for i = 1:height(ABC)
     L_sum(i) = sum(ABC{i, ABC.L(i,4:281)});
 end
```

Here my table:
[image]

**Problem**: My sum function sums the entire row values (col. 4-281) per date whereas I *only want those cells to be added whose headers are in the cell array of ABC.L*, for any given date.

---

X = ABC.L{1, 1}; gives (excerpt):

[image]

---

Red arrow: what sum function is referencing (L of same date).

Green arrow: what I am trying to reference now (L of previous date).
[image]

Thanks for your help

Comment: combination of cellfun and find?

Comment: can you write the value of ABC.L?

Comment: Yes. please see snapshot above, @MendiBarel!

Comment: You better look at "varfun" and "rowfun" functions.

Comment: how would the code look like for the above example, and how (& where) can I integrate the condition to look into ABC.L first, before doing the calculation? thanks

Comment: The green arrow is pointing the **next** record, not the previous. (It doesn't matter what date is written there...)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To do that you need to first extract the columns you want to sum, and then sum them:

```
% some arbitrary data:
ABC = table;
ABC.L{1,1} = {'aa','cc'};
ABC.L{2,1} = {'aa','b'};
ABC.L{3,1} = {'aa','d'};
ABC.L{4,1} = {'b','d'};
ABC{1:4,2:5} = magic(4);
ABC.Properties.VariableNames(2:5) = {'aa','b','cc','d'}

% summing the correct columns:
L_sum = zeros(height(ABC),1);
col_names = ABC.Properties.VariableNames; % just to make things shorter
for k = 1:height(ABC)
    % the following 'cellfun' compares each column to the values in ABC.L{k},
    % and returns a cell array of the result for each of them, then
    % 'cell2mat' converts it to logical array, and 'any' combines the
    % results for all elements in ABC.L{k} to one logical vector:
    col_to_sum = any(cell2mat(...
        cellfun(@(x) strcmp(col_names,x),ABC.L{k},...
        'UniformOutput', false).'),1);
    % then a logical indexing is used to define the columns for summation:
    L_sum(k) = sum(ABC{k,col_to_sum});
end
```

Comment: Thank you, @EBH, for your comprehensive help! It works smoothly

Comment: @John you welcome (and got an upvote for this tricky question...)

Comment: me again: when running the code, I detected that the following error message popped up: "Error using cellfun
Input #2 expected to be a cell array, was double instead." Is there an easy way to fix it? 
**thanks**

Comment: @John generally it means that `ABC.L{k}` is not a cell array, are you sure the data in `ABC` is as you wrote in the question?

Comment: yes. However I tried to manipulate the code in such a way that the `L_sum(k)` calculation at the end of the `for loop` takes into account not the entries of `ABC.L{k}` (current period) but rather the entries for "L" of the previous period (one row below). A simple indexing in `cellfun` to `ABC.L{k-1}` wasn't successful. Do you have an idea how to do that?

Comment: for clarification please see edited section above, @EBH.

Comment: @John, if you want to extract the columns of the next row you should write `strcmp(col_names,x),ABC.L{k+1}` and end the loop in `height(ABC)-1`. Also, you have to think what columns you sum in the last row (i.e., when there is no next row to extract from).

Answer (score 1):

In general, in matlab you dont need to use for loops to do simple operations like selective sums.
Example:

```
Data=...
    [1 2 3;
    4 5 6;
    7 8 9;
    7 7 7];

NofRows=size(Data,1);
RowsToSum=3:NofRows;
ColToSum=[1,3];
% sum second dimension 2d array
Result=sum(Data(RowsToSum,ColToSum), 2)

% table mode
DataTable=array2table(Data);
Result2=sum(DataTable{RowsToSum,ColToSum}, 2)
```